# Running Node Lib on Java Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, jsonpath, nashorn

I need running this library (https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath) on Java Nashorn. But when calling the "query" function, is returned this error: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such function query"

```
ScriptEngine nashorn = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
nashorn.eval("load('jsonpath.js')");

Invocable invocable = (Invocable) nashorn;
Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("query",  "[ { \"name\": \"JOHN\"}, { \"name\": \"KEVIN\"} ]", "$..name");
```

Comment: If I read the linked code right, the JavaScript call must be something like `JSONPath().query(...)`

Comment: I tried but it did not work :(